# Sklearn split Pandas Dataframe and CSR Matrix into Test and Training set

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification

i'm trying to classify text with scikit-learn DecisionTree and Pandas Dataframe:
First i constructed a dataframe which looks like this:

```
   cat1  cat2                             corpus           title
0     0     1                     Test Test Test    erster titel
1     1     0                   Test Super Super   zweiter titel
2     0     1                     Test Test Test   dritter titel
3     0     1                    Test Super Test   vierter titel
4     1     0                   Super Test Super  fuenfter titel
5     1     1         Super einfacher Test Super  fuenfter titel
6     1     1  Super simple einfacher Test Super  fuenfter titel
```

Then i'm generating a TF-IDF-Matrix:

```
_matrix = generate_tf_idf_matrix(training_df['corpus'].values)
```

which returns a csr-Matrix (CountVectorizer -> TfidfTransformer)

for my classifier i would like to use

```
    train_X = _matrix
    train_Y = training_df[['cat1','cat2']]
```

for a multilabel classification

My Question now is:

**How can i split my dataframe and my csr matrix into a test and a training set?
If i split my dataframe before i create the matrix, the csr matrix has another size because my documents have different features.**

Restriction: i don't want to convert my matrix to an array so i could easily split it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scikit-learns` package already contains a very powerful module for train-val-test cross-validation functions. You can have a quick look to the overall module [sklearn.cross_validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators) (here the [API](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.cross_validation)).

In general [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html#sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split) would do the job:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)
```

However, if your classes `y` are very unbalanced you might be interested in the [StratifiedShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit) which splits the data in train/test datasets, but keeping a percentaje of each of the classes in each of the train/test sets.

So in your case, first create your `X = _matrix` and `y = training_df[['cat1', 'cat2']]` and then use `scikit-learn`'s funtions to split it in train/test datasets.